# get table results by top 5 of most common table data

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

example table data:

```
id | name | tool
--------------------
 1 | bob  |   scissor
 2 | mike |   knife
 3 | john |   thread
 4 | joe  |   ruler
 5 | kim  |   marker
 6 | dean |   board
 7 | paul |   knife
 8 | john |   scissor
 9 | kim  |   ruler
 10| mike |   scissor
 11| mike |   board
 12| joe  |   board
 13| paul |   scissor
 13| jake |   marker
```

and would like to get the top 5 most common from the column 'tool' which would tell me something like

```
1 - scissor (4)
2 - board (3)
3 - knife (2)
4 - ruler (2)
5 - marker (2)
```

Comment: How is it different? You select tools and count(), then return the top X. Sounds the same to me.

Comment: in the above i tried `select top 5 'tool' from ( select 'tool', cnt=count(*) from 'tablename') t order by t.cnt DESC` and it didn't work for me.

Comment: `MySQL` doesn't have `top`. `SQL server` does. Please correct tags

Comment: understood. i lately reailized `top` is for MSSQL. i have removed the tag.

Comment: the question is intended for MySQL. i removed the related link in which the question was for SQL server.

Comment: FWIW, phrases like "it didn't work for me" aren't very informative. You need to be more specific. If you're getting an error, [edit] the question to include the full error message. Otherwise, include a brief description of the actual result and how it's different than what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the tools then order by the count limiting to 5.

```
select tool,count(tool) as nr_count
from test
group by tool
order by nr_count desc limit 5;
```

Result:

```
tool    nr_count
scissor 4
board   3
knife   2
ruler   2
marker  2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c95c05c966d262547f752a2cb599b3b

Note that you still have another tool with count of 2 results the above query doesn't take in consideration. You need to apply another order by